# uwsgi socket not created

Tags: sockets, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

I'm setting up an `ubuntu` server using `nginx` and `uwsgi`. Yesterday, running

`sudo service nginx restart`
and 
`sudo service uwsgi restart`

would generate this socket: `/run/uwsgi/app/recoapi/recoapi.socket`

I installed `uwsgi` using `pip` rather than `apt-get`, and ever since around that time, the `recoapi.socket` file hasn't been generated. I find the following error in my `nginx` `error.log` when I try to `curl` my server.

`2013/09/01 13:59:12 [crit] 29712#0: *1 connect() to unix:///run/uwsgi/app/recoapi/recoapi.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream`

The result of this error is that the output of my `curl` is

```
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.2.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

My `uwsgi` config file looks like this. The lines regarding the socket permissions seem to have no effect.

```
<uwsgi>
    <plugin>python</plugin>
    <uid>www-data</uid>
    <gid>www-data</gid>
    <chmod-socket>777</chmod-socket>
    <chown-socket>www-data</chown-socket>
    <socket>/run/uwsgi/app/recoapi/recoapi.socket</socket>
    <pythonpath>/var/www/recoapi/application/</pythonpath>
    <wsgi-file>/var/www/recoapi/application/wsgi_configuration_module.py</wsgi_file>
    <app mountpoint="/">

        <script>wsgi_configuration_module</script>

    </app>
    <processes>4</processes>
    <harakiri>60</harakiri>
    <reload-mercy>8</reload-mercy>
    <cpu-affinity>1</cpu-affinity>
    <stats>/tmp/stats.socket</stats>
    <max-requests>2000</max-requests>
    <limit-as>512</limit-as>
    <reload-on-as>256</reload-on-as>
    <reload-on-rss>192</reload-on-rss>
    <no-orphans/>
    <vacuum/>
</uwsgi>
```

I'm working from [this tutorial](https://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/python-uwsgi/ubuntu-12.04-precise-pangolin).

This is my `nginx` configuration file:

```
server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     $hostname;
        access_log /var/www/recoapi/logs/access.log;
        error_log /var/www/recoapi/logs/error.log;

        location / {
            #uwsgi_pass      127.0.0.1:9001;
            uwsgi_pass      unix:///run/uwsgi/app/recoapi/recoapi.socket;
            include         uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_param     UWSGI_SCHEME $scheme;
            uwsgi_param     SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;
        }

        location /static {
            root   /var/www/recoapi/public_html/static/;
        }
}
```

Comment: That's an altered Linode Config file, correct? I see you added the xml tags, uid, gid, chmod-socket and chown-socket. This resolved the issue for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

The problem was invalid syntax in my xml uwsgi file.

The socket wasn't being created because the server wasn't being started because it couldn't read the `uwsgi` config file, because I had mismatched `xml` tags: `wsgi-file` and `wsgi_file`. That line was unnecessary anyway, so I deleted it and the socket was created again.

Comment: In `/etc/uwsgi/site.ini`? This could be out of date, I don't see any `xml`

Comment: @surfer190 the xml part is out of date but the idea of the ini being incorrect is real still